# Flot X axis (Cannot output date)

Tags: php, javascript, flot

I'm trying to output the x axis with it's date. I'm currently using flot api and I want to output a date like xx/Mar/2012 on the x axis tick. Basically, I will push the date using graph.push[[tt, demand[i]]; where tt can be 28/Mar/2012. However, my graph does not produce this output on my axis, but instead, the values of -1 to 1.
Here's my code to push the date in:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= y; i += 1) {

var splitdates = dates[i].split(" ");

var tt = splitdates[0]+"/"+splitdates[1]+"/"+splitdates[2];

graph.push([tt, demand[i]]);
}
```

Here's my code to plot the x axis:

```
var options = {
series: {
        lines: { show: true },
        points: { show: true }
        },
        grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true },
        yaxis: { min: 0, max: 7000 },
        xaxis: {
        tickFormatter: function(value){
        return value;
        }
                             }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the flot API:

```
Note that to simplify the internal logic in Flot both the x and y values must be numbers
```

If you want string labels on the x axis, you need to make a separate array of "ticks" Search for the section "Customizing the axes" in the api.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DmXD6/)

In the case of dates though, flot has native support, and the format is customizable.  Search for the secion "Time series data" in the api.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QqU5D/2/)

Comment: As for the -1 to 1 issue, that may be an error in how you call the plot function.  Based on how you defined 'graph', you would need to use $.plot(placeholder, [data], options) as opposed to $.plot(placeholder, data, options)